# Simple C++ websocket server, can receive messages but failing with "failed: Invalid frame header" when sending messages

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, websocket, send

I am trying to make a simple websocket server in C++. I can connect to my server from my html/javascript page with:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:6001/websocket");
```

my server gets the following request

```
GET /websocket HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:6001
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:6001
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 4oyuqbJMJVtGRvVOd8KWKA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

and I reply with

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: QQphkELDd37KE7awCUPSOhWJI1k=
```

all good so far. I am able to send messages to my server with

```
socket.send("Hello World!");
```

which the server can successfully decode

```
Received data = ��56A$}S-HZKGZ%
---- WebsocketMessage ----
final        = 1
rsv1         = 0
rsv2         = 0
rsv3         = 0
optcode      = 1
masked       = 1
payload size = 12
payload      = Hello World!
--------------------------
```

but when I try to send a message from my server to my webpage, I always get the following error (chrome console):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6001/websocket' failed: Invalid frame header
```

Here's the code where I generate the frame (it's in a class so i'll include the member variables below too, all the variables are initialized earlier):

```
  bool                final_msg;
  bool                rsv[3] = { false, false, false };
  int                 optcode;
  bool                masked;
  unsigned long long  payload_size;

  std::string encode() {
      std::string msg;
      msg.push_back(
          (char) (final_msg ? 0x80 : 0x00) | (rsv[0] ? 0x40 : 0x00) | (rsv[1] ? 0x20 : 0x00) |
              (rsv[2] ? 0x10 : 0x00) | (0x0F & optcode)
      );
      msg.push_back(
          (char) (masked ? 0x80 : 0x00) | (0x7F & payload_size)
      );
      msg += payload;
      return msg;
  }
```

For now this function only works at packing messages < 126 bytes. Well, it's suppose to work but according to chrome it doesn't seem to. Here's the binary output for a test (PING) message:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

From the specs this should work and "socket.onmessage" should fire on my page, instead "onerorr" fires with "event.data = undefined".

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong? Or have any idea's how get some more helpful information? Thanks!

Comment: Jus t a thought... why are you using `^` with `payload_size` (instead of an `|`?

Comment: And where is the mask?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was just doing some incorrect encoding for the payload size. The function should read:

```
std::string encode() {
    std::string msg;
    msg.push_back(
        (char) (final_msg ? 0x80 : 0x00) | (rsv[0] ? 0x40 : 0x00) | (rsv[1] ? 0x20 : 0x00) |
            (rsv[2] ? 0x10 : 0x00) | (0x0F & optcode)
    );
    msg.push_back(
        (char) (masked ? 0x80 : 0x00) | (0x7F & payload_size)
    );
    msg += payload;
    return msg;
}
```

Thanks Myst and gre_gor for spotting this.